# Раздать интернет

Tags: linux, iptables, lan, route, модемы

Почему

```
$ ping ya.ru
ping: unknown host ya.ru
```

### Комп1 (принимающий инет)

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:03:05:c9:3e:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba03:5ff:fec9:3ec5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2797459 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:90723494 (90.7 MB)
```

```
и так делал
```

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.2 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2  metric 9
```

и так делал

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2  metric 9
```

```
$ sudo iptables-save
:пусто
```

```
$ nslookup ya.ru
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

---

### Комп2 (раздающий 3g)

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:67:d4:45  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:547759 (547.7 KB)  TX bytes:547759 (547.7 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.225.20.196  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13627 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:11287729 (11.2 MB)  TX bytes:2950024 (2.9 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:b7:c3:2a:68:31  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::52b7:c3ff:fe2a:6831/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1021 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:148348 (148.3 KB)  TX bytes:108966 (108.9 KB)

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:2c:80:13:92:63  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

```
$ ip route
default via 10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  metric 100 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.225.20.196 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1  metric 9
```

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Даже после команды :

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

в iptables пусто

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v -n --line
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11498 packets, 8572K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 112 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11183 packets, 2394K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

```
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Aug 12 21:04:53 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [437:43281]
:INPUT ACCEPT [389:28232]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1207:218579]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [66:9831]
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug 12 21:04:53 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Aug 12 21:04:53 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [29340:31886316]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [21601:3071749]
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Aug 12 21:04:53 2016
```

```
$ nslookup ya.ru
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 93.158.134.3
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 213.180.193.3
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 213.180.204.3
```

Сделал :

- iptables -F
- iptables -X
- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
- iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
- iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

Получил

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 4357 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 65 packets, 3965 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 88 packets, 13008 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 890 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   90 12510 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Но маскарад так и не работает.

---

В итоге на комп2 есть инет и пингуется комп1. А на комп1 нет инета,хотя и пингуется комп2. Почему нет интернета ?(

Comment: Дык, Вы добавляете правило в mangle NAT, но смотрите его совершенно не так. Сначала сбросьте текущие правила `iptables -F` и `iptables -X` затем добавьте `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE` затем убедитесь что оно добавилось `iptables -t nat -nvL` ещё наверно не помещал бы форвардинг `iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` и `iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, вывод команды `sudo iptables-save` на обоих компьютерах. внести изменения в вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: А что у вас используется на первом компе в качестве DNS-сервера? Покажите вывод `nslookup ya.ru` и `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Все сделал как просили.

Comment: Ну теперь задание посложнее: на "комп1" запустить `ping 8.8.8.8`, а на "комп2" поочерёдно с промежутком в секунд 15 запускать `tcpdump -ni wlan0 host 8.8.8.8` и `tcpdump -ni ppp0 host 8.8.8.8` - где-то там Вы должны увидеть трафик от "комп1" в следствии чего определить, на каком этапе теряются пакеты.

Comment: Короче гугл пинговался нормально, но после чего начал, уже не плнятно. прописал на 1ом (без инета) компе /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8 и СЧАСТЬЕ ПРИБЫЛО !

Comment: Указание `nameserver` не может избавить от `connect: Network is unreachable` при `ping 8.8.8.8`, увы. В любом случае, всё хорошо - что хорошо кончается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На обоих компах прописал в файл /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Спасибо @alexander-barakin

Сделал на компе2(с 3g инетом):

- iptables -F
- iptables -X
- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
- iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
- iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

Спасибо @nobody

И заработало. Всем спасибо!)

Comment: из пяти приведённых команд нужна (и несёт какой-то смысл) только третья.

Answer (score 3):

так как в вопросе не упомянут [файл `/etc/resolv.conf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf), скорее всего, в нём и дело.

в этом файле сохраняется информация, необходимая системе для преобразования доменных имён в ip-адреса (и обратно).

как минимум в нём должна присутствовать строка вида:

```
nameserver ip-адрес
```

где `ip-адрес` — это адрес [dns-сервера (сервера имён)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80), который, собственно, и выполнит (при обращении к нему со стороны вашей системы) упомянутое выше преобразование (например, `ya.ru` → `93.158.134.3`).

чем «ближе» находится сервер имён, тем быстрее будет получен от него ответ. вы можете взять адрес из аналогичного файла со второго компьютера. или воспользоваться каким-нибудь публичным:

- `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4` ([поддерживаются компанией google](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS))
- `77.88.8.8`, `77.88.8.1` ([поддерживаются компанией yandex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.DNS))

Comment: Комп с инетом 

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
____________________
комп без инета,  у него только комментарии, не было nameserver
Пробывал ставить 8.8.8.8 , 192.168.0.1, 127.0.0.1 ничего.

Comment: это локальный ip-адрес. что-бы не морочить себе голову, смело ставьте адрес любого публичного dns-сервера (примеры в ответе).

Comment: ну так это работет норм на компе с инетом, такой ИП, я знаю что такое 127.0.0.0/24, 168.0.0.0/24, 10.0.0.0/24,  пробывал другие ИП ДНС вписывать не помогает.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554522/#comment715446_554522

Comment: и вывод команды `$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` на втором компьютере.

Comment: В главном посте написано. Вообщем там(на 2ом компе с инетом) 1 стоит.

sudo iptables-save описал в главном посте

Comment: что именно в данный момент выводят команды `$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`, `$ ip r` и `$ ip r get 8.8.8.8`  на первом компьютере? добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. также, я думаю, не помешает и вывод `$ sudo iptables-save` на первом компьютере.

Comment: и, на всякий случай, вывод `$ ip ru` на обоих компьютерах.